# Two references of the same model in another Rails: 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I ask if it is good to have two references of one model in another and if it can do it how do I do it?

Problem: I have a record that will be controlled by two users (both always different users) and I need to have them see the records they have.

picture example:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pucMa.jpg)

The idea is that both can have access to the same registry and no one else can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to achieve many to many association, I would suggest you to use **has_many_through** association. you can read about it over [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

your tables will be like:

```
User:
```

`id, email, name` and other fields related to user

```
Box:
```

`id, name` and Fields related to boxes

`User_Boxes:` (Join table for mapping users with boxes, to do what you're trying to achieve)

```
id, user_id, box_id
```

so, 
according to your diagram:

**let the id's of boxes in box table be:**

1. box home
2. box 2
3. box closet
4. box keys

**Your mapping table would look like:**

```
id   box_id   user_id

1       1      1
2       1      3 
3       2      5
4       2      9
5       3      1
6       3      9
7       4      7
8       4      2
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Making a lot to many only for 2 users with different roles is a lot to me but if it is the right way

Comment: @J.leo it is :)